# Aligning or integrating features from two feature classes using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, alignment, map-matching, integration

I am trying to align two line feature classes (street networks) that have been digitalized differently - see picture. One is more spatially accurate and has the attributes I need (A) and the other one has more detail in terms of small streets (B) - and I want both ;-)

They don't share any fields like ID or name.

The problem I have is that two or more features of the two feature classes can represent the same "street". If that is the case, I need to get rid of the said features of one of the feature classes. And since I dont want to lose the attributes of feature class A, I need to somehow get rid of the features of class B. My approaches so far:

- Using the integrate tool to integrate features from class B into class A, to then delete them using "delete identicals" or topology rules. However, the tool miraculously changes the geometry of almost all features from class B even if the next feature from class A is much further away than the XY-tolerance defined.

I tried it anyway because I didn't know any other method. But:

- Using the integrate tool and then delete identicals does not work,
  since the features are not identical, even though they overlap. E.g.
  one feature class is digitalized using three short line features to
  represent one street, while the other feature class uses one long
  feature.)
- Using the integrate tool to make the features overlap and then use repair topology to subtract one from the other. However, I have 4400 errors and can only fix them one by one. It seems there is no way to batch fix them.

Is there any way to get rid of these redundant features?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and I m new here so pls tell me if the question needs editing or additional information.

[image]

Comment: Convert one Layer Feature Vertices to Points. With Spatial Join determine the Line ID that each Point intersects. If all Points of a Line intersect the same ID, is it a Duplicate?

Comment: Thanks klewis! I guess the answer is "no". But i m not sure if I get the question right. I added a screenshot with the layers and vertices of one of them.

Comment: Have you thought of transferring the attributes from the red to a copy of the blue layer with Spatial Join or other method? This way the Lines would exactly match.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem. But since the features dont always intersect or even intersect with the wrong feature from the other layer a simple spatial join wont help. I just found this and will try it out: http://www.cfgis.org/getattachment/17d13c63-435b-4dc2-8e6e-548e5a1bcb91/Performing-Spatial-Joins-on-Polyline-Shapefiles.aspx

Comment: You might try the unsplit tool on your 3 part lines to make them a single feature.  If you were able to get B to match A using the Integrate tool, you could try using a select by location method (you may have to try different ones) to select B's lines that overlap A's, reverse the selection and then merge A to the selected B.  (I have to admit looking at your diagram I wouldn't think the Integrate tool wouldn't leave a lot of manual work.  If you find that to be true you might try the snap tool, although you might have to densify first then unsplit after.)